# Como usar o pep8 no Vscode?

Tags: python, json, visual-studio-code, pep8

adicionei a extensão no arquivo settings.json, mas quando compila não mostra o erros no padrão que deveria, como posso adicionar o PEP8 e testar no vscode?

Comment: Vá nas configurações da extensão em `python.formatting.provider` defina para `autopep8`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vá nas configurações da extensão e pesquise pela config `python.formatting.provider` em seguida defina o valor para `autopep8`, veja abaixo:

[image: config extensão]

Veja na [documentação](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_formatting) do Visual Studio Code.